# Why Windows throws "Not trusty program" when I run my compiled exe in another computer?

Tags: c++, windows, warnings, executable

Everytime I copy my file and then run it in another computer (The same system *Windows 10* and the same version), Windows throws me a warning saying that my program is not trusty. Also, when I download it using Google Chrome, it also throws me a warning saying "This program may contain viruses, it's unsafe downloading it.". Well, I can run it correctly by clicking "Still trust it" | "Keep downloading", but it looks very unsafe when other people use it.

By the way, my compiling environment:

```
 - Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community
 - Visual C++ 2019
```

Comment: Might be windows defender warning from suspicious behavior. Without knowing what your program does it is impossible to trust it. 

If you want the error to lift you should sign your executable.

Comment: Do you [sign your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-sign-a-package-using-signtool)?  You will need to apply for (and pay for) a code signing certificate to do this.  I use Comodo, mainly because it is relatively inexpensive.

Comment: I think the process goes like this:  on your own machine, when you compile and link the program, the code is self-signed.  That self-signed credential is authenticated on that dev machine.  But the other machine has no knowledge of that dev self-signed credential, so the other machine treats the program as untrusted.  Using a signing authority allows your certificate authority to grant your program a trusted status (unless the authority revokes the trust).  I'm sure there is way more to it than my synopsis.  I just wanted to give you the gist of what is going on.